# How to apply a lambda function to the Pandas DataFrame.groupby using a group-specific condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have been trying to apply a lambda function to a column in a dataframe after groupby, but with a conditional in the function that is specific to each group. Please see the following:

```
df.groupby('column_1')['column_2'].apply(lambda x: a if x == df.groupby('column_1')['column_3'] else x)
```

The purpose is to group the dataframe by column_1, and change the values of column_2 depending on the corresponding values in column_3 **within the same group**.

This is the error I get: "invalid type comparison"

By the way, column_2 and column_3 are both integers.

I have also set a conditional on a value rather than a series. Because the values of column_3 within each group is the same, I have tried to add ".first()" to the conditional:

```
df.groupby('column_1')['column_2'].apply(lambda x: a if x == df.groupby('column_1')['column_3'].first() else x)
```

This is the error I get: "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Any thoughts on how to fix this, or an alternative implementation?

Thanks much!

```
Sample data:
column_1 column_2 column_3
0        0        2
0        1        2
0        2        2
0        3        2
1        0        0
1        1        0
1        2        0
1        3        0

Expected output:
column_1 column_2 column_3
0        0        2
0        1        2
0        a        2
0        3        2
1        a        0
1        1        0
1        2        0
1        3        0
```

Comment: sample data & expected output please.

Comment: I don't get it isn't it just a comparisson of the columns like { df['column_2'] = np.where(df['column_2'] == df['column_3'], 'a', df['column_2']  ) }. What is the reasoning behind the grouping?

Comment: Yep, you are right. It looks like I have obsessed with groupby. I have come to this problem from another problem where grouping was necessary. What do we do now? Should I delete the question? or Is this still a reasonable problem to think about?

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier solution. If your goal is to compare values from two columns by group then you do not need to add a second grouping. Just pass a function that will compare the columns you want in the grouping

Here is an example. First I generate some sample data and sort it by the first column, 'a', which I'll treat as the grouping column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 20
data = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size = (n,3))


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns = list('abc')).sort_values(by = 'a')

df
Out[15]: 
    a  b  c
9   0  1  1
1   0  0  1
2   0  1  1
3   0  1  2
4   0  1  0
5   0  0  1
6   0  2  1
7   0  1  2
8   0  1  0
16  1  2  2
13  1  0  1
0   1  1  0
18  1  0  2
19  1  1  2
12  2  0  0
10  2  2  1
14  2  1  0
15  2  0  0
17  2  0  1
11  2  0  0
```

Then, I apply the grouping and comparison.

```
df.groupby(by = 'a').apply(lambda frame: frame['b'] == frame['c'])
a    
0  9      True
   1     False
   2      True
   3     False
   4     False
   5     False
   6     False
   7     False
   8     False
1  16     True
   13    False
   0     False
   18    False
   19    False
2  12     True
   10    False
   14    False
   15     True
   17    False
   11     True
dtype: bool
```

Not sure how I missed this, but you have

"*The purpose is to group the dataframe by column_1, and change the values of column_2 depending on the corresponding values in column_3 within the same group.*"

Then, a solution may be to use the resulting Truth values  like

```
bools = df.groupby(by = 'a').apply(lambda frame: frame['b'] == frame['c']).values

df['test'] = df['b']

df['test'].loc[~bools] = df['c'].loc[~bools]
```

Comment: Thank you, but at the last line, the values in the new "test" column end up being the same as the values in the "c" column.

Comment: You can replace that with whatever values you need. I just did that as an example.

Comment: I meant "df['test'].loc[~bools] = df['c'].loc[~bools]" behaves as "df['test'] = df['c']."

Comment: I disagree with this answer. You really don't need apply here.